# Is there a way to detect changes to the content control in word in office js?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-contentcontrol, word-web-addins

I've got a script that finds all matching bits of text and puts them in a content control. I noticed there was a functionality to remove the content control if the text was edited `ContentControl.removeWhenEdited = true`. Is there a way to run this same trigger/event of when the text content changes, but instead of removing the content control trigger some custom code instead?

I figured since there's already functionality to trigger on the exact event I need, it surely can't be too complicated. I tried `ContentControl.onDataChanged = MyFunction()` but this only ran the function when the content control was added and couldn't rerun it when the data was infact changed.

Any and all help greatly appreciated!